# Ruby When use and pass parameters to functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to redirect the user in the authetication method if the request format is html or json, but always just show as the json format has been requested.

I've passed the (html and json) as parameters!
Someone know if this is the right way to pass the parameters?

```
def authenticate_user!(html,json)
    if request.format.html? && current_user.nil? 
      redirect_to login_url, notice: "Not authorized" 
    else 
       request.format.json? && current_user.nil? 
      redirect_to download_url, notice: "you need download the file first"

    end

  end
```

Comment: You're declaring two parameters there, but not using them, also there's a repeated line there, can you explain what you're doing?

Comment: Sebastian, i'ḿ trying to redirect the user according with the request on authentication.
if the user is already authenticated he is not redirected.

Comment: i did get yet how the parameters works so i passed because this functions is always redirecting as json even on chrome

Comment: Does something like this work? `def authenticate_user!
  message = case request.format
            when html? then 'Not authorized'
            when json? then 'you need download the file first'
            end
  redirect_to login_url, notice: message
end`

Comment: Sebastian thank you but, show a error!

Comment: undefined method `html?'

Comment: message = case request.format when html?

Comment: is a good way to use then, when?

Comment: Try instead `when :html` and `when :json`. Wondering if it should be json or js.

Comment: i did already, did no worked just show

Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: @lula can u show, how do u call or where do u call this `authenticate_user!` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t need to add parameters. The controller knows the format.

```
def authenticate_user!
  if current_user.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to login_url, notice: 'Not authorized' }
      format.json { redirect_to download_url, notice: "You need download the file first" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Pablo, thank you very much. o thought that respond_to was just to use for standard controller actions.